# powershell copy creates extra empty folders

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

i'm using this simple command to copy over some files and folders that get dropped into a temp folder.

```
copy c:\update_temp\* c:\target\ -recurse -force
```

say update_temp has following structure

```
c:\update_temp\first_file.txt

c:\update_temp\first_folder\anotherfile.txt
```

when i run the command, here is what i end up with

```
c:\target\first_file.txt

c:\target\first_folder\anotherfile.txt

**c:\target\first_folder\first_folder**
```

not sure why that last entry is happening, so now i end up with a ton of unnecessary folders.

I'm running powershell v1

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Could have been a bug. Doesn't happen to me in v2.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not actually sure why that folder is being created, but I think you want to call copy without the *:

```
copy c:\update_temp\ c:\target\ -recurse -force
```

This will recursively copy update_temp to target.

What you're doing is copying everything under update_temp to target. That's subtely different and while I can't quite puzzle out why you end up with first_folder\first_folder, I am certain that isn't what you want.